# HTML Canvas Touch events with Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas

[image]

Hi,

I am making a touch enabled signing app using 2 HTML Canvas. In the screenshot attached below, i am able to sign on my tablet on 1st canvas and on the second canvas as well without scrolling the scroll-bar on the right. If i scroll and bring the 2nd canvas in complete focus, then my signing stops working on the 2nd Canvas. It seems that on scrolling i am not calculating the coordinates well.

Here is the code that i am using to get the co ordinates and pass that to my Drawer method.

```
                   var coors = {
                        x: event.targetTouches[0].pageX ,
                        y: event.targetTouches[0].pageY 
                    };

                    // Now we need to get the offset of the canvas location
                    var obj = signCanvas;

                    if (obj.offsetParent) {

                        do {
                            coors.x -= obj.offsetLeft;
                            coors.y -= obj.offsetTop;
                        }

                        while ((obj = obj.offsetParent) != null);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
   var rect = signCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();  // absolute position of canvas
   var coors = {
        x: event.targetTouches[0].clientX - rect.left,
        y: event.targetTouches[0].clientY - rect.top
    };
```

and of course, comment out/remove the rest of the adjustment code for the coordinates.